# Created a new site collection on SharePoint online but couldnt able to locate it in Manage site collections from admin page.

Tags: sharepoint-online

Created a new site collection on SharePoint online but couldnt able to locate it in Manage site collections from admin page.

When i tried to access the site directly by URL, it show access required page. I have the SharePoint Admin access on the portal.

Comment: how did you create it ? can you share the steps/code ?

Comment: From the admin page, "new" - "create a private site collection".

Comment: Tried on a different browser? Or a new session of the same browser?

Comment: I did, i also tried with a different admin credentials.